# Advanced search for subject incurs error 438 - object doesn't support this properties or method

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, inbox

I would like to search for email with subject "order 14567" in my current Outlook folder.

There is an error (438 - object doesn't support this properties or method.) incurred in the following code:

```
Set objSch = Application.AdvancedSearch(scope:=strS, _
            Filter:=strF, Tag:=strTag)
```

**VBA code:**

```
Sub SearchInboxFolder()
'Searches the Inbox
    Dim objSch As Search
    Const strF As String = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject = 'order 14567'"
    Const strS As String = "Inbox"
    Const strTag As String = "SubjectSearch"
    Set objSch = Application.AdvancedSearch(scope:=strS, _
        Filter:=strF, Tag:=strTag)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [IsInstantSearchEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861239(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Store returns false, i.e. the instant search is turned off for the store. In that case you need to use the search string like the following one:

```
"urn:schemas:mailheader:subject like '%order 14567%'"
```

You can read about filtering strings in the [Filtering Items Using Query Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869374.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) section in MSDN.

Also you may find the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods of the Items class helpful. They are described in depth in the following articles:

- [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/)
- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Hi eugene, I change my line to "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject like '%order 14567%'", still not working on Set objSch = Application.AdvancedSearch(scope:=strS, _
        Filter:=strF, Tag:=strTag), I was thinkg if i need to add any extra VBA reference?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check out the the [IsInstantSearchEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861239(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Store class?